# How can I solve a 'Could not Reach Firestore Backend' error on a client which DOES have a healthy network connection?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Using a React app hosted on Firebase, and the Firebase-js sdk, one specific client is unable to access the Firestore database and authentication.
The error: @firebase/firestore: Firestore (9.19.1): Could not reach Cloud Firestore backend. Backend didn't respond within 10 seconds. This typically indicates that your device does not have a healthy Internet connection at the moment. The client will operate in offline mode until it is able to successfully connect to the backend.

However, clients on the same network do not have any issues accessing the Database - it is only this computer, and other browsers do not yield different results. All network tests show that the connection is normal and healthy.

Performed a Firebase-js upgrade to see if that helped - it did not.

Ran the 'https://debug-my.firebaseapp.com' debugger and came up with the following results:

```
All tests done.
1: webchannel.googleapis.com with default options: FAILED (40468ms)
2: webchannel.googleapis.com with detectBufferingProxy: FAILED (39902ms)
3: webchannel.googleapis.com with forceLongPolling: FAILED (39881ms)
4: webchannel.sandbox.google.com with default options: FAILED (40647ms)
5: webchannel.sandbox.google.com with detectBufferingProxy: FAILED (39860ms)
6: webchannel.sandbox.google.com with forceLongPolling: FAILED (39882ms)
7: Firestore listen test with default options: FAILED (75022ms)
8: Firestore listen test with detectBufferingProxy: SUCCEEDED (3027ms)
9: Firestore listen test with forceLongPolling: SUCCEEDED (1071ms)
```

but unfortunately that doesn't tell ME anything meaningful.
All other machines using this site don't have any similar issues.